# Plugin Permission Javascript check

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, plugins, user-agent

I know you can check for useragents with javascript, but can you also check to see if plugins have been blocked from operating on your page?

The page in question loads the Sibelius Scorch Plugin, and it loads properly for Firefox, Safari, and IE... but Chrome automatically blocks the plugin, and continues to do so until you have selected "Continue to Block" or "Allow this Plugin"

Since some of the users of this site don't read at all, I would like to add a styled status message that alerts the user "HEY, can't see the plugin working? Click ALLOW in the upper right hand corner of your Chrome browser".

Like I said, this error only occurs in Chrome, other browsers automatically allow the plugin to execute.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The easiest way would be to check `typeof(functionName) === "function"`, where functionName is something specific to the plugin in question.

Comment: How would I even implement that? i'm not doubting this is correct, I just never knew you could check for plugins before now, which is why I asked.